# Aptana Studio 2 - Adobe AIR 2.0 Plugin Missing

Tags: aptana

I have Aptana Studio 2 (Build 2.0.5.1278522500) and have used it to build an Air app using the AIR 1.5 Plugin.  I need some Air 2.0 functionality, but when I go to the Help > Install Aptana Features, the only AIR plugin listed is the 1.5 one.

I have un-installed Studio 2 and re-installed, thinking I had inadvertently deleted the plugin, but no luck.  I don't find the plugin anywhere on the web to download.

Any ideas?

Rob

Comment: So after hours of searching, I post this question -- then keep looking and find the answer.  Go to Help > Install New Software.  Then on the Install screen, click the 'Available Software Sites' link.  Then Enable the air site.  When you are back on the Install screen, choose the air option from the Work with drop-down.  From there you can install the Air 2.0 plugin.

Comment: You should make that comment an answer